# Конструктор класса cStringIO.StringIO

Tags: python, python-2.x

Читаю чужой код. Увидел, что в одном месте в конструктор класса `cStringIO.StringIO` попадает строка. Не могу разобраться на что она влияет и зачем нужна в конструкторе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбираться в данном случае нет нужды - надо всего лишь открыть [документацию](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#cStringIO.StringIO). Цитата:

> Another difference from the StringIO module is that calling StringIO()
>   with a string parameter creates a read-only object. Unlike an object
>   created without a string parameter, it does not have write methods.
>   These objects are not generally visible. They turn up in tracebacks as
>   StringI and StringO.

Еще одно отличие от модуля `StringIO` - вызов конструктора со строковым параметром. В этом случае будет создан объект только для чтения и у него не будет никаких методов для записи. Такие объекты обычно невидимы. Они представлены как `StringI` и `StringO`.

Ради интереса еще можно полистать [исходники](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_io/stringio.c) cStringIO. Конкретно в [этой](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_io/stringio.c#l774) строке можно подсмотреть конструктор - объект создается с заранее предустановленным свойством `STATE_REALIZED`. Затем при [попытке записи](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_io/stringio.c#l218) проверяется наличие другого свойства и кода для состояния `REALIZED` просто нету - потому что аккумулятор, в котором хранятся данные должен быть [уничтожен](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_io/stringio.c#l142). Эти состояния объясняются так: `In accumulating state, the internal buffer contains nothing and the contents are given by the embedded _PyAccu structure. In realized state, the internal buffer is meaningful and the _PyAccu is destroyed`. Мне, однако, неведомо зачем инициализировать объект с уже заданной строкой таким образом.